# How to emulate LOST UPDATE in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, concurrency

Database name: dbmcw. 
Table: lost_update_demonstration. 
Columns: worker_id, salary. 
I am trying to emulate lost update in Postgresql. I have taken code from [here](http://www.confio.com/logicalread/sql-server-concurrency-lost-updates-w01/#.UznjGqh_vy4). Code is for SQL Server. I changed code to fit to my database. But I dont know does it fit Postgresql or not.

```
/* TRANSACTION 1*/
USE dbmcw;
DECLARE @sal int = 0;
BEGIN TRAN;
SELECT @sal = salary
FROM dbmcw.lost_update_demonstration
WHERE worker_id = 1;
SET @sal = @sal + 10;
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05.000';
UPDATE dbmcw.lost_update_demonstration
SET salary = @sal
WHERE ProductID = 1;
SELECT salary
FROM dbmcw.lost_update_demonstration
WHERE worker_id = 1;
COMMIT TRAN;

/* TRANSACTION 2*/
USE dbmcw;
DECLARE @sal int = 0;
BEGIN TRAN;
SELECT @sal = salary
FROM dbmcw.lost_update_demonstration
WHERE worker_id = 1;
SET @sal = @sal + 20;
UPDATE dbmcw.lost_update_demonstration
SET salary = @sal
WHERE worker_id = 1;
SELECT salary
FROM dbmcw.lost_update_demonstration
WHERE worker_id = 1;
COMMIT TRAN;
```

When I run this code, Postgresql is giving this error: ОШИБКА:  ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "USE"). Translation: "ERROR: syntax error(location : "USE"). 
LINE 2: USE dbmcw;

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`USE` is not a [valid command in PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-commands.html). Must be an artifact from your SQL server code. Connecting to a database is not part of the SQL code in Postgres.

Much of the code is completely invalid in Postgres. For instance, there are no variables ins plain SQL: `@sal` You'd have to use [PL/pgSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql.html) or another procedural language.

You need to completely rewrite this. But that's asking too much from an answer. Do your homework first.

Answer (score -1):

See https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-database-locking-and-the-lost-update-phenomena/ for more information about lost update problem. It shows how you can simulate lost update with two simultaneous database transaction

[image]

and presents two possible solutions to prevent this problem:

- Repeatable read isolation level
- SELECT ... FOR UPDATE